# How to get file names from a SharePoint folder

Tags: asp.net-core, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get the name of all the files in a folder but I don't know how to do it. This is my code

```
var items = await client
             .Sites["xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx-xxx-xxxx....,xxxx-xxx-xxxx...."]
             .Drives[":/drives/Documentos"]
             .Request()
             .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, when I try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/drive_id/root/children`, I can get all the items in the root folder. Since I don't have a sharepoint site, so I can't test with a sharepoint site, but it should be similar. If you don't want to get all the elements in root folder, you can then follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-id) to get specific item children items with `/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children`.

```
var files = await client.Sites["xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx-xxx-xxxx....,xxxx-xxx-xxxx...."]
                   .Drives[":/drives/Documentos"].Root.Children.Request().GetAsync(); 
foreach(var file in files)
{
      var fileName = file.Name;
}
```